# HTML Scroll navigation

Tags: css, html

How can I create a scroll navigation, like on the chanel website?  http://www.chanel.com/en_CA/

When you scroll another page will scroll up. Whats the name of that and how is it
done?

Comment: Please share some thoughts/ideas you had and/or some code you've already worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the technique they used is called Parallax Scrolling.
Here is a quick tutorial on how to create it: 
https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/

Answer (score 0):

Try fullpage.js + stellar.js in combo to achieve this.

Stellar (http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)
FullPage(https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/)

Pages are very well documented and easy to start